# Magento: Save customer billing address in session

Tags: magento

I'm developing a multi-store shop on magento. The problem is that the customers should be redirected to the nearest shop possible.

The solution I'm trying to implement is to put a half-transparent div overlay on page and ask for street name and number, and based on these values redirect the customer to the right store.

The issue I'm facing right now is that I don't know how to save that address in session, that later on checkout I wouldn't ask them once more.

What I tried to do is:

```
$address = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
$address->setStreet('test_value');
$address->save();
```

However after a single refresh the information is gone.

How would you recommended me to do this?

**UPDATE:**

- All stores are on the same website, so I think the session is the same (at least the cookie doesn't change, I checked).
- In 90% of all cases the customer will be unregistered, is in this case the solution with customer ID applicable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes because you saying that you are going to different store, which means different session so these values are not carried over... I would recommend a controller call (with the base url of the store you want to carry the cart over to) with parameter the quote id and the store id where from it is being redirected and the customer id... and reset session in the controller... basically do:

set customer

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->load($customerId));
```

set quote

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setParentQuoteId($quoteId);

foreach (Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($originalStoreId)->load($quoteId)->getAllItems() as $quote_item) {
            $this->addToBasket($quote_item);                
}
```

set vouchers etc if any and then redirect back to basket.

Should work